# calculate time with server data livestampjs momentjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

As I can make livestampjs momentjs take the date of my server and not the client, since the date of the customer can be wrong

//html

Comment: I don't really know momentjs, but you could pass the UNIX epoch (the `new Date().getTime()`) of the client which is not wrong I think.

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek It's wrong if client's computer has a wrong date

Comment: What are we looking at? the xml is faulty.

Comment: @ Oriol is why I need to know is how I take it from the server and not the client, any ideas?